# need to specify queue name with user name and password for activemq java code

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to write a simple java code that connects to activeMQ queue, I found [this](http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/08/activemq-introduction.html) resource online which basically follow the [Hello World](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) example in activeMQ site. I'm trying to specify username and password alongside a queue name and I'm unable to find any helpful resource online, so any help would be highly appreciated.

I made the following changes in the producer code and I'm not sure how to specify factory name and if I'm specifying username and password correctly?

```
            // First create a connection
            InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
            javax.jms.ConnectionFactory qcf = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) initCtx.lookup(factoryName);
            Connection connection = qcf.createConnection("admin","admin");
            connection.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
                "tcp://localhost:61616");
        props.put("topic." + "TOPICNAME", "TOPICNAME");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
        ConnectionFactory cf1 = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        writeDestination = (Topic) ic.lookup("TOPICNAME");
        writeDestConnection = cf1.createConnection("user", "pwd");
        writeDestConnection.setClientID("durableSubscriber_" + "TOPICNAME");
        writeDestSession = writeDestConnection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        writeDestProducer = writeDestSession.createProducer(writeDestination);
        writeDestConnection.start();
        TextMessage message = writeDestSession.createTextMessage(json);
        message.setStringProperty("clientID", "ifYouNeed");
        writeDestProducer.send(message);
```

http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html

here is another example without jndi:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        conn = cf.createConnection("user", "pwd");
        Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue("queueName"));
        conn.start();
        TextMessage msg = null;
        while ((msg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Received message is: " + msg.getText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Hassen for your answer! I'm wondering if there is another way to connect to activemq queue without using JNDI?

Comment: I updated my response with consumer sorry but this part (producer code) is the same than jndi example